# Change JTextField scrollpane text padding/offset by some pixels

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to align the position (start + end) of text inside a JTextField, but i haven't been able to find and/or understand how to do this...

[example of what is wrong and what i'm looking for:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssmMQ.png)

The setHorizontalAlignment method only allows this..:

```
•JTextField.LEFT 
•JTextField.CENTER 
•JTextField.RIGHT 
•JTextField.LEADING 
•JTextField.TRAILING
```

With android projects, this is so easy...but for the sake of me, i can't figure this one out, when doing a swing project...How can this be done?

**EDIT:**

I've been able to sort this one, by using double (aka layered) JTextFields. emptyborder(), although easier code wise, removes all JTextField frame borders, leaving you with a big empty square, which, for an input box, it's not a good idea...here's a picture and some code sample:

[JTextField Padding Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJHIJ.png)

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TextBoxOffset {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("JTextField, using CreateEmptyBorder");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        label1.setBounds(0, 125, 284, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

        //Creates a new JTextField with a emptyborder
        JTextField emptyborder = new JTextField();
        emptyborder.setBounds(22, 164, 250, 43);
        emptyborder.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 17, 5, 15));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyborder);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("JTextField, using double (layered) JTextFields");
        label2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label2.setBounds(0, 22, 284, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label2);

        // Creates a new input field, layered above the (disabled) JTextField background object
        JTextField inputbox = new JTextField();
        inputbox.setBounds(40, 61, 216, 31);
        inputbox.setBorder(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(inputbox);

        // Creates a border for the input text field that will serve as a background
        JTextField bg = new JTextField();
        bg.setBounds(22, 56, 250, 43);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bg);
        bg.setEnabled(false);

        // Grab the overlayed inputbox focus
        inputbox.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

If anyone knows a better, easier way of doing this, meaning, control the text padding on all sides (TOP,LEFT,BOTTOM,RIGHT), inside a JTextField (or any other field for what matters (e.g.: control the position of the text inside a button) without using double JTextFields, please post a reply.

Comment: Try adding caretlistener to your text field ,Check this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/CaretEventsandListeners.htm

Comment: caretlistener, only reads the position of the caret - it's not exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to add a Border to your text field:

```
textField.add( new EmptyBorder(...) );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

> i can't figure this one out, when doing a swing project.

Keep the link to the Swing tutorial handy for Swing basics.

Edit:

Oops, I forgot a JTextField also has a special method to control this:

```
textField.setInsets(...);
```

So you don't need the CompoundBorder, however so you still be aware of the flexibility provided by a CompoundBorder.

Comment: yes, EmptyBorder() does allow you to have some control over the top, left, bottom, right paddings, inside a JTextField...but with a major drawback: you loose all JTextField borders, forcing you to: a) add a background image, "cheating" the effect of having a JTextField Border (note: using static images might cause problems if you need to resize the window dynamically!); b) having a layered JTextField, with it's own border (effectively invalidating the purpose of having EmptyBorder() all together). I've edited my question and added a working example with the latter.

Comment: @JoaoAlonso, then you can use a `CompoundBorder`. The `CompoundBorder` can contain the original border and the empty border. Read the tutorial it has an example of a `CompoundBorder`.

Comment: Thank you, camickr! Using CompoundBorder did the trick! Using setMargins with setInsets, does work but did had some limitations when redrawing the textfield (on my main project, i'm changing the color border when getting textinput focus, and it is documented that there's some limitations to it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29 ).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is by using :

```java
textField.setMargin(new Insets(...));
```

I was looking for the same kind of result and this literally made my day, I hope it'll help others too.